# Как отследить удаление приложение и присылать уведомление?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

Есть задача, сделать так, чтобы при удалении какого либо приложения с телефона, моё приложение присылало уведомление, удаленно такое-то приложение.

Делаю это следующим образом:

Manifest

```
      <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="servicereload" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
        notificationManagerCompat.cancelAll()

        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent)
        } else {
            startService(Intent(this, MyService::class.java))
        }
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)
        intentFilter.addDataScheme("package")
        registerReceiver(MyReceiver(), intentFilter)

    }
}
```

MyReceiver

```
class MyReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    val CHANNEL_ID = "ServiceChannel"
    @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        var packageName = ""
        try {
            packageName = Objects.requireNonNull(intent!!.data)!!.encodedSchemeSpecificPart
            Toast.makeText(context, "USER UNINSTALL : $packageName", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.i("MyLog", "USER UNINSTALL : $packageName")
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.i("MyLog", "Exception: $ex")
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            val notificationManager = context!!.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }

        val notifyIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 200, notifyIntent, 0)

        val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, CHANNEL_ID).apply {
            setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            setContentText("App ${packageName.substringAfterLast(".")} has been deleted")
            priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
        }

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context!!)) {
            notify(200, builder.build())
        }

    }

}
```

MyService

```
class MyService : Service() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.i("MyLog", "onStartCommand()")
        someTask()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.i("MyLog", "Service onDestroy()")
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = "servicereload"
        intent.setClass(this, MyReceiver::class.java)
        this.sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.i("MyLog", "Service onCreate()")
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, this.javaClass)
        intent.setPackage(packageName)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val alarmManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,1000,pendingIntent)
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    }

    private fun someTask() {
        Log.i("MyLog", "Service someTask()")
//        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
//        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)
//        intentFilter.addDataScheme("package")
//        registerReceiver(MyReceiver(), intentFilter)
        Thread {
            for (i in 1..50) {
                Log.i("MyLog", "Service i = $i")
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
//            stopSelf()
        }.start()
    }
}
```

Метод someTask(), просто чтобы видеть, что сервис запущен и работает.
Проверяю на эмуляторах API 29+, если успеть до 10секунды удалить прилу, работает хорошо но запускает второй сервис параллельно что не хорошо, и я не понимаю почему?! Если не чего не делать, после 10 секунд выдает `android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{ab817c0 u0 com.testappremovel/.MyService}`
Если убираю onDestroy() или onTaskRemoved() в сервисе, нет проблемы с параллельным запуском но после 10 секунды вырубается в любом случае и соответственно не включается обратно.
Еще у меня есть методы для определения названия и иконки приложения по пакету, чтобы выводить их в уведомлении, но понятное дело когда приложение уже удаленно, достать эти данные я не могу.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать чтобы все работало как надо?

Comment: Написано же: после запуска сервиса, не был вызван метод `startForeground()` - это обязательное условие для работы сервиса на "переднем плане". https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#start

Comment: В сервисе надо уведомление создать, тогда ошибки не будет

Comment: Добавил, ошибка пропала но после удаления какого-то приложения или после перехода по этому уведомлению сервис запускается по второму и даже третьему разу параллельно, как сделать так чтобы такого не происходило(и при этом если он отключится он включился заново), или это норма?

Comment: Смотрите что бы не создавался заново, в манифесте пропишите не закрывать при выходе из приложения

Comment: @ArtyMorris я так понимаю имеется в виду android:stopWithTask="false"? Но если верить логам он все равно создается по новой

Comment: Тогда где то в коде намудрили. Или сделайте проверку, на запущенность сервиса. В инете есть примеры